# Playground vs. Simulator - Why Does Simple View Render Differently?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3

I am experimenting with playgrounds so as to expand my capacity to use them to do rapid prototyping. I have created a simple view controller which is adding/centering a button to/in its view. I have duplicated the view controller code in a project and in a playground. When I execute the project in the simulator the button **is centered**. When I execute the playground the button **is not centered**. Would someone please help me to understand why this is happening?

I have included 3 screenshots:

1. Xcode Project With View Controller Code
2. Simulator Showing the Result of Executing the Project
3. Playground With View Controller Code and Timeline Showing the Execution Result

[image: Xcode Project With View Controller Code]
[image: Simulator Showing the Result of Running the Project]
[image: Playground With View Controller Code and Timeline Showing the Execution Result]

Per @Paulw11's comment, here is the updated and working view controller code:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

let button = UIButton(type: .System)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2

    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 20)
    button.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
    button.setTitle("Rotate", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rotate), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(button)

    print("View: size is \(view.bounds.width) x \(view.bounds.height), centered @\(view.center)")
    print("Button: size is \(button.bounds.width) x \(button.bounds.height), centered @\(button.center)")
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    button.center = view.convertPoint(view.center, fromView: view.superview)
}

func rotate() {
    print("Rotate")
}
```

}

Comment: Please post code, not screen shots. You can't rely on the superview frame until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Just as a note you don't need the `@` before strings in swift.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much. And, in the future, I'll be sure to post the code (along with any needed screen shots).

Comment: Daniel - The @ is part of the string, it prints.